# count number of rows in a data frame in R based on group

Tags: r, dataframe, rowcount

I have a data frame in `R` like this:

```
  ID   MONTH-YEAR   VALUE
  110   JAN. 2012     1000
  111   JAN. 2012     2000
         .         .
         .         .
  121   FEB. 2012     3000
  131   FEB. 2012     4000
         .           .
         .           .
```

So, for each month of each year there are `n` rows and they can be in any order(mean they all are not in continuity and are at breaks). I want to calculate how many rows are there for each `MONTH-YEAR` i.e. how many rows are there for JAN. 2012, how many for FEB. 2012 and so on. Something like this:

```
 MONTH-YEAR   NUMBER OF ROWS
 JAN. 2012     10
 FEB. 2012     13
 MAR. 2012     6
 APR. 2012     9
```

I tried to do this:

```
n_row <- nrow(dat1_frame %.% group_by(MONTH-YEAR))
```

but it does not produce the desired output.How can I do that?

Comment: try looking at ?aggregate. I think you want `aggregate(VALUE ~ MONTH-YEAR, data = dat1_frame, FUN = function(x){NROW(x)})`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto will `table()`  give me number of rows for each month of each year? I have modified the above post to show what I want as an output

Comment: @AndyClifton I am not concerned about `VALUE` column in my data frame. I just want the total count/number of rows for each month.

Comment: @AnandaMahto there 3 columns. There is one column in the beginning which is sort of ID for each row but is not of my concern

Comment: I have added the ID column in my above data set example. I hope this what you meant by "reproducible example"

Comment: jason, `aggregate()` just needs something to count as function of the different values of `MONTH-YEAR`. In this case, I used `VALUE` as the thing to count. See answer.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here's an example that shows how `table(.)` (or, more closely matching your desired output, `data.frame(table(.))` does what it sounds like you are asking for.

Note also how to share reproducible sample data in a way that others can copy and paste into their session.

Here's the (reproducible) sample data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(ID = c(110L, 111L, 121L, 131L, 141L), 
                       MONTH.YEAR = c("JAN. 2012", "JAN. 2012", 
                                      "FEB. 2012", "FEB. 2012", 
                                      "MAR. 2012"), 
                       VALUE = c(1000L, 2000L, 3000L, 4000L, 5000L)), 
                  .Names = c("ID", "MONTH.YEAR", "VALUE"), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

mydf
#    ID MONTH.YEAR VALUE
# 1 110  JAN. 2012  1000
# 2 111  JAN. 2012  2000
# 3 121  FEB. 2012  3000
# 4 131  FEB. 2012  4000
# 5 141  MAR. 2012  5000
```

Here's the calculation of the number of rows per group, in two output display formats:

```
table(mydf$MONTH.YEAR)
# 
# FEB. 2012 JAN. 2012 MAR. 2012 
#         2         2         1

data.frame(table(mydf$MONTH.YEAR))
#        Var1 Freq
# 1 FEB. 2012    2
# 2 JAN. 2012    2
# 3 MAR. 2012    1
```

Answer (score 61):

The `count()` function in `plyr` does what you want:

```
library(plyr)

count(mydf, "MONTH-YEAR")
```

Comment: That's working well, thank you. What if I want to print the ID along with this result. In other words, Id to MONTH.YEAR and the Count has to appear.

Comment: At the time `dplyr` would be the equivalent for `plyr`.

Answer (score 22):

Try using the count function in dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
dat1_frame %>% 
    count(MONTH.YEAR)
```

I am not sure how you got MONTH-YEAR as a variable name. My R version does not allow for such a variable name, so I replaced it with MONTH.YEAR.

As a side note, the mistake in your code was that `dat1_frame %.% group_by(MONTH-YEAR)` without  a `summarise` function returns the original data frame without any modifications. So, you want to use

```
dat1_frame %>%
    group_by(MONTH.YEAR) %>%
    summarise(count=n())
```

Comment: You can use variable names containing characters like `-` by quoting the string with backticks. For example, `\`MONTH-YEAR\``

Comment: I use this recipe every time when I need to accomplish this kind of task. I find this recipe easy to read-easy to remember.
Upvoted.

Answer (score 19):

Using the example data set that Ananda dummied up, here's an example using `aggregate()`, which is part of core R. `aggregate()` just needs something to count as function of the different values of `MONTH-YEAR`. In this case, I used `VALUE` as the thing to count:

```
aggregate(cbind(count = VALUE) ~ MONTH.YEAR, 
          data = mydf, 
          FUN = function(x){NROW(x)})
```

which gives you..

```
  MONTH.YEAR count
1  FEB. 2012     2
2  JAN. 2012     2
3  MAR. 2012     1
```

Comment: I think `FUN = function(x){NROW(x)}` can be replaced by just `NROW` or `length`.

Comment: Yes, correct. But imagine you wanted to use the same approach for a slightly different function, or you wanted to add an naomit() - you need to use the longer form shown here.

Answer (score 8):

Just for completion the data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)

mydf <- structure(list(ID = c(110L, 111L, 121L, 131L, 141L), 
                       MONTH.YEAR = c("JAN. 2012", "JAN. 2012", 
                                      "FEB. 2012", "FEB. 2012", 
                                      "MAR. 2012"), 
                       VALUE = c(1000L, 2000L, 3000L, 4000L, 5000L)), 
                  .Names = c("ID", "MONTH.YEAR", "VALUE"), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

setDT(mydf)
mydf[, .(`Number of rows` = .N), by = MONTH.YEAR]

   MONTH.YEAR Number of rows
1:  JAN. 2012              2
2:  FEB. 2012              2
3:  MAR. 2012              1
```

Answer (score 6):

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data, .(MONTH-YEAR), nrow)
```

This will give you the answer, if "MONTH-YEAR" is a variable.
First, try unique(data$MONTH-YEAR) and see if it returns unique values (no duplicates).

Then above simple split-apply-combine will return what you are looking for.

Comment: That won't work. `data$MONTH-YEAR` will try and subtract a vector called `YEAR` from the `MONTH` column. Either quote the name: `unique(data$"MONTH-YEAR")` or use a dot in the name. I'm pretty sure the `ddply` example will fail too.

Comment: @Spacedman Yeah you are right. Made a bad example of naming the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of using `aggregate` to count rows by group:

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
    month.year    my.cov
      Jan.2000     apple
      Jan.2000      pear
      Jan.2000     peach
      Jan.2001     apple
      Jan.2001     peach
      Feb.2002      pear
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = NA)

rows.per.group  <- aggregate(rep(1, length(my.data$month.year)),
                             by=list(my.data$month.year), sum)
rows.per.group

#    Group.1 x
# 1 Feb.2002 1
# 2 Jan.2000 3
# 3 Jan.2001 2
```

Comment: Why not just `aggregate(my.cov ~ month.year, my.data, length)`?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a df_data data frame as below

```
> df_data
   ID MONTH-YEAR VALUE
1 110   JAN.2012  1000
2 111   JAN.2012  2000
3 121   FEB.2012  3000
4 131   FEB.2012  4000
5 141   MAR.2012  5000
```

To count number of rows in df_data grouped by MONTH-YEAR column, you can use:

```
> summary(df_data$`MONTH-YEAR`)

FEB.2012 JAN.2012 MAR.2012 
   2        2        1
```

[image]
summary function will create a table from the factor argument, then create a vector for the result (line 7 & 8)

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".