# How can you count how often each date appears in a data set?

Tags: r, datetime, counting

I am working with a large health related database. Each event has a datetime tag on it. Example:

```
Admission DateTime
2016-12-20 03:04:05
2016-12-20 12:07:00
2016-12-20 13:11:15
2016-12-21 03:04:05
2016-12-21 03:04:05
2016-12-21 08:08:01
2016-12-22 05:05:05
2016-12-22 05:10:44
2016-12-23 03:04:25
```

What I would like from this data is to see how many times does a certain datetime appear. Specifically days. I know how to round down the datetime in R, but I am have trouble going from that step to the table below (which is my desired outcome):

```
Admission DateTime, Occurrences
2016-12-20, 3
2016-12-21, 3
2016-12-22, 2
2016-12-23, 1
```

Is there anyway I can do this in R without utilizing any packages (Installing packages needs permission from IT staff, and that can take a while to get).

Comment: Your desired output is misleading.  2016-12-20 does not occur 3 times at 03:04:05 in the data set.  Same with the next two rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count number of rows in a data frame in R based on group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293045/count-number-of-rows-in-a-data-frame-in-r-based-on-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table` should do the trick:

```
table(as.POSIXct(c("2016-12-20 03:04:05", "2016-12-20 12:07:00", "2016-12-20 12:07:00")))
```

You can wrap `as.data.frame(...)` around this expression to obtain a data frame.

Comment: Yes, I tried you method and with the data frame wrap I'm able to get a really nice looking data frame, the only issue is that the values are wrong (I did some simple SQL spot checking).

Comment: For example, running the program i would get 200 entries for 12-20-2016, but the SQL search comes up with around 600. Could it be with how I am rounding the datetimes? I am using this:
'dates <- round(My_data, "days")'

I'm trying to have the Data just reflect the days section of the datetime, and ignore the hours and minutes that come before it.

I apologize for the messy content, I am new here.

Comment: `table(as.Date(...)) ` works for the sample input in my answer; the problem with `round` may come from it returning a `POSIXlt` list.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. `round` caused a few unforeseen issues. I caved in and got lubridate and used the `floor_date` function instead. And then with your answer, I was able to get the correct answers. Thank you, I really appreciate the feedback/input.

Answer (score -1):

Should you eventually use dplyr and the hallowed Tidyverse:

```
  library(dplyr)
  dataset%>%
  group_by(Datetime)%>%
  summarize(n=n())
```

Comment: I don't think you _need_ `dplyr` for this. Also, if you're going tidyverse you could simply use `count(dataset, Datetime)`.

Comment: I got down voted for suggesting the tidyverse? Good Times

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `dplyr`. Suggesting to a possibly new user that he _needs_ to use `dplyr` for a simple frequency table is perhaps a little misleading though.