# R: how to aggreate rows by count

Tags: r, aggregate, grouping

This is my data frame

```
ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
favFruit=c('apple','lemon','pear',
       'apple','apple','pear',
       'apple','lemon','pear',
       'pear','pear','pear')
surveyDate = ('1/1/2005','1/1/2005','1/1/2005',
         '2/1/2005','2/1/2005','2/1/2005',
         '3/1/2005','3/1/2005','3/1/2005',
         '4/1/2005','4/1/2005','4/1/2005')

df<-data.frame(ID,favFruit, surveyDate)
```

I need to aggregate it so I can plot a line graph in R for count of favFruit by date split by favFruit but I am unable to create an aggregate table.  My data has 45000 rows so a manual solution is not possible.

```
surveyYear   favFruit  count
1/1/2005       apple     1
1/1/2005       lemon     1
1/1/2005       pear      1
2/1/2005       apple     2
2/1/2005       lemon     0
2/1/2005       pear      1
... etc
```

I tried this but R printed an error

```
df2 <- aggregate(df, favFruit, FUN = sum)
```

and I tried this, another error

```
df2 <- aggregate(df, date ~ favFruit, sum)
```

I checked for solutions online but their data generally included a column of quantities which I dont have and the solutions were overly complex.  Is there an easy way to do this?  Thanx in advance.  Thank you to whoever suggested the link as a possible duplicate but it has has date and number of rows.  But my question needs number of rows by date and favFruit (one more column) [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293045/count-number-of-rows-in-a-data-frame-in-r-based-on-group)

Update:
Ronak Shah's solution worked.  Thanx!

Comment: `df2 <- aggregate(surveyDate ~ favFruit, df, length)`. See help page of `?aggregate` for examples and syntax.

Comment: Thanks, but the code lists favFruit and total count.  How can it be broken down by surveyDate also?  I am having trouble with that.   I checked the recommended link above but it is not the same question because it is missing another factor.

Comment: You can do `aggregate(ID~favFruit + surveyDate, df, length)`. To avoid confusion it is always better to include the expected output in your post.

Comment: It worked! thanks!!

Comment: I am not sure how to designate it as the solution.  I am sure others will have the same question.  Do you know how?

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by Ronak is very good.
In case you prefer to keep the zero counts in your dataframe.
You could use `table` function:

```
data.frame(with(df, table(favFruit, surveyDate)))
```

Output:

```
   favFruit surveyDate Freq
1     apple   1/1/2005    1
2     lemon   1/1/2005    1
3      pear   1/1/2005    1
4     apple   2/1/2005    2
5     lemon   2/1/2005    0
6      pear   2/1/2005    1
7     apple   3/1/2005    1
8     lemon   3/1/2005    1
9      pear   3/1/2005    1
10    apple   4/1/2005    0
11    lemon   4/1/2005    0
12     pear   4/1/2005    3
```