# How Can I Aggregate A Column of Strings By Frequency

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have the following data frame formatted as such:

```
     x     y
    2001 Apples
    2001 Apples
    2001 Apples
    2001 Oranges
    2001 Oranges
    2002 Apples
    2002 Apples
    2002 Apples
    2002 Apples
    2002 Oranges
    2002 Oranges
    2002 Oranges
```

How could I combine this aggregate this data so the result would be like this:

```
     x     y      Frequency
    2001 Apples       3
    2001 Oranges      2
    2002 Oranges      3
    2002 Apples       4
```

I know that tables are good for showing frequency, but I am not sure how to aggregate this data? I have tried doing something like `aggregate(df1$x ~ df1$y, df1, FUN = sum)`, but that did not yield the expected results.

Comment: Just use `table(df1)`

Comment: That shows the frequency, but it does not aggregate.

Comment: Isn't that you want i.e. getting the count. `table` returns a table object, which can be converted to data.frame `as.data.frame(table(df1))`

Comment: No, I am looking for something like this. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879551/frequency-count-of-two-column-in-r

Which I have now, so it's not a problem.

Comment: `as.data.frame(table(df1))` gives the expected as in your post

Comment: First create a new column `Count`: `df["Count"] <-1` then use `aggregate`:
`aggregate(df[c("Count")], by=df[c("x", "y")], FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `base` R functions;

```
df1 <- read.table(textConnection('x     y
    2001 Apples
    2001 Apples
    2001 Apples
    2001 Oranges
    2001 Oranges
    2002 Apples
    2002 Apples
    2002 Apples
    2002 Apples
    2002 Oranges
    2002 Oranges
    2002 Oranges'),header=T)

data.frame(table(df1))
```

**output;**

```
  x     y        Freq
  <fct> <fct>   <int>
1 2001  Apples      3
2 2002  Apples      4
3 2001  Oranges     2
4 2002  Oranges     3
```

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` approach:

```
x <- c(2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002)
y <- c("Apples","Apples","Apples","Oranges","Oranges",
       "Apples","Apples","Apples","Oranges","Oranges","Oranges","Oranges")

df <- tibble(x = x, y = y)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  count(x,y,name = "Frequency")

# A tibble: 4 x 3
      x y       Frequency
  <dbl> <chr>       <int>
1  2001 Apples          3
2  2001 Oranges         2
3  2002 Apples          3
4  2002 Oranges         4
```